# Zoom and have cursor for a matplotlib plot within iPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Within Google-colaboratory, I cannot use `matplotlib. use(TkAgg)`.

The possibility that it offers to me is though very helpful:

I can zoom in my plot interactively and also get a cursor that shows me the present values of x and y where my mouse is hovering over.

Is there anything similar within iPython / Jupyter that has a similar functionality?

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook` (comes with matplotlib) or `%matplotlib widget` (needs [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) installed)

Comment: thanks, that was very helpful for a jupyter beginner. For the alternatives I found at https://medium.com/@1522933668924/using-matplotlib-in-jupyter-notebooks-comparing-methods-and-some-tips-python-c38e85b40ba1 presently only `!pip install mpld3` 
`import mpld3` 
`mpld3.enable_notebook()` does offer some functionality (namely: zooming and moving the plot). A value help for the hovered mouse is missing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these snippet, both zooming and the hovered mouse x/y cursor works in google colab:

```
!pip install mpld3
!pip install "git+https://github.com/javadba/mpld3@display_fix"
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(a, "-o", markersize=2)
plugins.connect(fig, plugins.MousePosition(fontsize=14))

mpld3.display()
```

Comment: This seems to encounter the error: "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mpld3/mplexporter/utils.py in get_grid_style(axis)

AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute '_gridOnMajor'"